# Manipulating Registry Script with Python

Tags: python, registry, windows-xp, remote-desktop, winreg

I have created the following script to nullify the IE page setup.

```
from winreg import *

Target = r"\\IT-OZ"

def Nullify_PageSetup(Target):
    aCon = ConnectRegistry(Target,HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
    bCon = OpenKey(aCon,r"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\PageSetup",0,KEY_WRITE)

    SetValueEx(bCon,"margin_bottom",0,REG_SZ,"0")
    SetValueEx(bCon,"margin_left",0,REG_SZ,"0")
    SetValueEx(bCon,"margin_right",0,REG_SZ,"0")
    SetValueEx(bCon,"margin_top",0,REG_SZ,"0")

Nullify_PageSetup(Target)
```

The Script works perfectly on the local computer.
but I have created it to change page setups of computers in my network.

When I switch the "Target" to a network computer, it pops an error of

```
" FileNotFoundError: [WinError 53] The network path was not found ".
```

Any idea how I might get this working? or does "WINREG" module supports only local registry?

Kind Regards!

Comment: You should just use the command-line REG command. And use Python to call it with Subprocess.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick answer Inbar. But I'm very new to python, Would you please give a further explantion? From what I understood, you are suggesting to do it in a whole other way?

Comment: Do you get the same error when using the REGEDIT.EXE-program?

Comment: Hi Mikpa. I have connected to the registry of the target computer after I enabled "Remote assistance" on it. Yet I'm only able to see 2 hives, "Local" or "Users". My wanted hive is "Current User". I cant seem to understand why I get limited options(I'm admin). any idea of how to solve this one?

Answer (score 0):

You should enable and start "Remote Registry" service. It helps me on Windows 10.